# Django rest framework: checking IF employee.SSN exits then let employee complete the sign up the account

Tags: python, django-rest-framework

### First

I extend the User model and make it Custom for my needs and here is the model

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin,TrackingModel):
    """
    An abstract base class implementing a fully featured User model with
    admin-compliant permissions.

    Username and password are required. Other fields are optional.
    """
    username_validator = UnicodeUsernameValidator()

    username = models.CharField(
        _('username'),
        max_length=150,
        unique=True,
        help_text=_('Required. 150 characters or fewer. Letters, digits and @/./+/-/_ only.'),
        validators=[username_validator],
        error_messages={
            'unique': _("A user with that username already exists."),
        },
    )
    email = models.EmailField(_('email address'),blank=False, unique=True,error_messages={'unique':'A user with that email already exists.'})
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(
        _('staff status'),
        default=False,
        help_text=_('Designates whether the user can log into this admin site.'),
    )
    is_active = models.BooleanField(
        _('active'),
        default=True,
        help_text=_(
            'Designates whether this user should be treated as active. '
            'Unselect this instead of deleting accounts.'
        ),
    )
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(_('date joined'), default=timezone.now)
    objects = MyUserManager()

    EMAIL_FIELD = 'email'
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['username']

    @property
    def token(self):
        return ''
```

### Second

I have another Model Employee which has a **one-to-one** relation with **User_Model**.

```
class Employee(models.Model):
    gender = (('m','male'),('f','female'),('n','notset'),)
    ssn =models.CharField(max_length=14,validators=[MinLengthValidator(limit_value=14)],unique=True,null=True,)
    fname = models.CharField(max_length=200,null=True,blank=True)
    lname = models.CharField(max_length=200,null=True,blank=True)
    six = models.CharField(max_length=1,choices=gender,default='n')
    img =  models.ImageField(upload_to='employee/',null=True,blank=True)
    user = models.OneToOneField(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True,blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.fname
```

### What I need:

1. the admin Add just the Employee **SSN**
2. then when employee go to registration form, it ask him to verify **SSN**
3. if alraedy SSN added by admin
4. then let him complete employee_info(fname,lname,img,six) and user_info(username,email,password)
5. else send message "ask admin to add you" (admin just add the SSN)
6. Finally, the employee login with normal Email,password to the whole system

### Do I need Two tokens?

1. One for Complete signup after verifying Employee.SSN
2. another to log in to the system

## This is my first Time Working with API.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

You can check via `Employee.objects.filter(SSN=your_ssn).exists()` to see if SSN exists or not.

Comment: in other word, how to create a token when check that employeeSSN is in the database, so that i can use it in complete registration form. and when login I generate another token to use it in the whole website ** I am newbie in django Rest framework**

Comment: I am not sure about what you are asking.

Comment: I Edited my question, hope you understand what I want.